# Ansible ArubaOSS multiple vlan ids and ports

Tags: linux, networking, automation, ansible, vlan

I got the follwing task for my aruba aoss switch in my ansible playbook:

```yaml
- name: update vlan with ports
  arubaoss_vlan:
  vlan_id: 2
  name: "vlan 2"
  config: create
  command: config_vlan_port
  port_id: "1"
  port_mode: "POM_TAGGED_STATIC"
```

I would like to do the tagging with multiple vlan_ids on multiple port_ids how is this possible?